# Dijkstra's own implementation using PostGres & PostGIS

Tags: postgis, openlayers-2, postgresql

I'm currently working on a travel routing application and would like to implement my own version of Dijsktras or A*.

I've been looking at PostGres & PostGIS for storing OSM data, added using tools such as OSM2PO.

I know there are tools such as pgrouting that can be used, but is there any resources/guides on how one would avoid pgrouting and create a custom route algorithm?

The end goal is to show a shortest path route from A -> B (possible waypoints) on a map such as OpenLayers.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use pgRouting - the work has already been done, especially when dealing with OSM data...

Comment: It's for an academic project, whereby implementing the algorithm is required. I can't use a purely canned solution

Comment: First you will need a graph with nodes, edges and costs but I do not quite understand what is your question.

Comment: I would like to perform my own implementation of an algorithm such as Dijkstra's on OSM data. I can import it into a DB such as PostGres using parser tools, but wanted to know how I could actually implement the algorithm myself instead of using pgrouting. I'm sure others have done it before, but I can't find any information

Comment: Have you considered to read some academic papers about routing algorithms and the source code of pgRouting?